# Angularjs:trying to make an asyn call on start of my application doesn't return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In my app i am trying to load the angular JS constant on start of my application by reading from json file by making a asynchronous call and as soon as code hit the asynchronous call it goes and does other bits and then return to .then block of code.

Is there a wait to stop execution until it finish the asynchronous  call in angular JS??

Example:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {

    'use strict';


    app.config(function ($provide) {  

        var serviceUrl=null;

        var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

        var $http = initInjector.get('$http');      

         var responsePromise = $http.get('/scripts/config.json');
         responsePromise .then(function (response) {
             serviceUrl = response.data;
             $provide.value('serviceURL', serviceUrl); 
         },function (response) {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong...');
        });

    });

    return app;
});
```

Comment: I suggest you use RequireJS to achieve this. [See here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx) Although this talks about controllers, we've used to it load services and other scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you using `app.run()` method for this:

```
app.run(['$http, $provide', function($http, $provide){
    // your code
}]);
```

As far as I know, you cant make `$http` methods run synchronously. All of them return a promise, which resolves async. But you can wait in your code until promise resolves like this:

```
var lock=false;

$http.post(...).then(function (results) {
  // your code

  lock=true;
});

while (!lock) {
  // We're just waiting.
}

// code that should be executed after you get something with your request
```

**Second** option is to use `jQuery.ajax({async: false})` to run request synchronously

Comment: The problem with this is that the app execution will continue immediately after the `$http` call is executed, which is what the OP wanted to prevent.

Comment: Did you noticed `while (!lock) {}` block?

Comment: Thank you,but option one doesn't work for me as i get error "Unknown provider: $http,$provideProvider <- $provide"when using app.run and second i cannot use $http.post as i get json file not found.

Comment: I don't have a while block in code.Above example code is in a config.js file located in app directory of angularjs-requirejs project.This config.js file loads up at start of the application along with routes.js file.

Comment: $provide is a dependency you ask angular to inject. copied from your code. Use $http.get() instead of $http.post() if you need.